# How to hide the Manage password bar above the keyboard for non password textboxes in android Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard

When I focus in any textbox field, the Password suggestion bar/Manage password board is displayed above the keyboard. In our case, it’s giving very small display for the user to visualize the typed information. I have tried several options like:

- Disabling auto-save password
- Removing existing saved passwords in the chrome
- Disabling keyboard/password settings present in the chrome://flags

Nothing works for me. This looks like a defect as this Manage Password bar is showing up regardless of the field type is password or not. Is there any alternate option/ workaround not to show this bar? It’s working fine for Firefox though.
[Defect screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVLEp.jpg)

Comment: It seems to me it is a bug in Chrome https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/167858494/password-bar-above-keyboard-on-android-phone-always-there?hl=en